# event.stopPropagation() not working in firefox javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, stoppropagation

event.stopPropagation() Does not work as it should be in the Firefox browser, but in Google Chrome or Internet Explorer or opera it is works well, the problem in Firefox browser when Clicking on btn_1 should show message btn_1  not show div1 .Is there another function or a solution to this problem? Gratefully

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Hello!</title>
<style type="text/css">
  <!-- body {
    text-align: center;
  }
  #main {
    position: absolute;
    height: 400px;
    width: 600px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    left: 400px;
  }
  #btn1 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    left: 500px;
    top: 420px;
  }
  #btn2 {
    position: absolute;
    height: 30px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    left: 800px;
    top: 420px;
  }
  #div1 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #FF3399;
  }
  #div2 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #99FF00;
    position:relative;
  }
  #div3 {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #00CC99;
  }


  -->
</style>
<script>
  function addElement2() {

    var element = document.getElementById("main");
    while (element.firstChild) {
      element.removeChild(element.firstChild);
    }

    var newContent = 0;


    for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {


      newContent = newContent + 1;

      var divname = "div" + newContent;
      var divname2 = "div" + newContent;
      var Content_text = "newContent" + newContent;


      divname = document.createElement("div");
      document.getElementById("main").appendChild(divname);
      Content_text = document.createTextNode(divname2);

      divname.id = divname2.toString().trim();
      divname.appendChild(Content_text);

        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON")
           document.getElementById(divname2.toString().trim()).appendChild(btn);

                 var btn_id=  "btn_" + newContent;
                    btn.id =btn_id;




   var  Content_text2 = document.createTextNode("btn_" + newContent);
    btn.appendChild(Content_text2);
       btn.onclick =  function(){delete_cooke1(this) ;} ;
        divname.onclick =  function(){go_to(this) ;} ;

    }
  }

  function delete_cooke1(mmm){
             event.stopPropagation();
        var str =    mmm.id.toString() ;

              alert(str);
               return;
             }


    function go_to(mmm){

        var str =    mmm.id.toString() ;

              alert(str);
               return;
             }



</script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main"></div>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="addElement2()">1-Create 3 divs</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can use `return false;`

Answer (score 1):

You will need to explicitly pass the `event` object into your callback function. For example:

```
document.querySelector("body").onclick = function(e){
    console.log(e); // the current event
};
```

You are taking advantage of the fact that Chrome exposes the current event as a global [on the window](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_access.html) (i.e. `window.event` or just `event`). Firefox does not do this -- and [other browsers](http://help.dottoro.com/ljogqtqm.php) are affected as well.

Comment: Thank you nathanallen  Can you embed it in the previous example and resend with thanks

Answer (score 1):

Calling `event.preventDefault()` worked in my case.

I have a react app and I was calling event.stopPropagation() inside the onclick handler of a material-ui checkbox like so:

```
<StyledCheckBox
  icon={<CircleUnchecked />}
  checkedIcon={<CircleChecked />}
  checked={shipmentEditIds.includes(id)}
  onClick={event => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    setShipmentEditIds({ id });
  }}
/>
```

For some reason, only in firefox browser, this wasn't stopping the event from propagating.
Once I added `event.preventDefault()` to the onClick handler it fixed the problem.

I know this doesn't provide an answer as to why `stopPropagation()` isn't working in Firebox browser but just sharing what worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Pass event from onclick:

```
btn.onclick =  function(){delete_cooke1(this, event) ;} ;
```

And use `event` argument with `stopPropagation()`

```
function delete_cooke1(mmm, e){
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.preventDefault(); // Add this line also
     var str =    mmm.id.toString() ;
     alert(str);
     return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is still ... a message show div1 not btn_1 Use Mozilla Firefox 45.0 , with many thanks and appreciation

Comment: i Use Mozilla Firefox 45.0

Comment: Unfortunately Same result